# Spatialite - Editing points

Tags: spatialite, sqlite

I have a few hundred invalid x-coordinates on points in my database, as a result of a GPS logger malfunction. Database is Spatialite, GPX-files were imported with [gpx2spatialite](https://github.com/ptrv/gpx2spatialite).

As they are messing up my tracks, I'd like to replace these invalid x-coordinates with the average of the x-coordinates of the preceding and succeeding point.

The table I'm viewing the coordinates in is a virtual table:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "idx_trackpoints_geom" USING rtree(pkid, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

It seems this virtual table uses as its sources these tables:
idx_trackpoints_geom_node
idx_trackpoints_geom_parent
idx_trackpoints_geom_rowid
The idx_trackpoints_geom.pkid for my faulty row matches idx_trackpoints_geom_rowid.rowid, which gives me idx_trackpoints_geom_rowid.nodeno, which then lead me to idx_trackpoints_geom_node.data. However, it's datatype BLOB...

The faulty point:
xmin: 0.850792
xmax: 0.850792
ymin: 60.231220
ymax: 60.231228

Here's the output (1228 hex bytes) of HEX(idx_trackpoints_geom_node.data); this does not appear to adhere to the BLOB format described in the [documentation](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/BLOB-Geometry.html).

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

Is there any reasonably sane way to manually edit a point in Spatialite?